# Аргументы метода как константы заданного интерфейса

Tags: php, php7, enum

У меня реализован интерфейс

```
interface TypesInterface {
    const TYPE_ELEMENT  = 22;
    const TYPE_SECTION  = 32;
    const TYPE_PRODUCER = 43;
}
```

Далее мои классы имплементируют этот интерфейс и используют эти константы.

Встала такая задача, что необходимо, новому классу в конструктере в качестве аргумента передать одно из значений констант этого интерфейса.

Т.е, что-то подобное (нерабочий пример):

```
public function __construct(TypesInterface $entityType) {
  ...
}
```

Т.е. аргументы могут быть только константами данного интерфейчас.

В С++ такой тип данных называется ENUM. 
Насколько понял, в php ничего адекватного, похожего на enum нету.
Только SplEnum, и то, смотрел что с ним бывают проблемы при работе с доктриной.

Может есть идеи как решить проблему адекватным способом ?

Comment: [PHP: Всё, что вы хотели узнать об интерфейсах](https://habr.com/ru/post/328890/) : `Почему же константы в интерфейсах не получили широкого распространения в промышленном коде, хотя и используются иногда? Причина в том, что их невозможно переопределить в интерфейсе-наследнике или в классе, реализующем данный интерфейс. Константы интерфейсов — самые константные константы в мире :)`

Comment: Этот факт для меня не нов. Не совсем понял, что изменится, если буду использовать  константы классов? Как это решит мою задачу?

Answer (score 0):

Начал изучать интерфейсы и случайно наткнулся на этот вопрос. Мне стало интересно решить данную задачку. Данный код тестировался на PHP 8.1.3:

```
interface Value {
const TYPE_ELEMENT  = 22;
const TYPE_SECTION  = 32;
const TYPE_PRODUCER = 43;
function __construct($Element, $Section, $Producer); 
}



class User implements Value {
private $constants;

function __construct($Element = 22, $Section = 32, $Producer = 43){
$this->constants = [
self::TYPE_ELEMENT => $Element,
self::TYPE_SECTION => $Section,
self::TYPE_PRODUCER => $Producer
];
}


public function getType($type) {
return $this->constants[$type];
}


function show(){
$values = [
$this->getType(self::TYPE_ELEMENT), 
$this->getType(self::TYPE_SECTION), 
$this->getType(self::TYPE_PRODUCER)
];

$a= 0;

foreach($values as $items){
echo  ++$a . " - $items <br>";
}}
}


$obj = new User(1,2,3);
echo $obj->show();
```

Comment: вообще-то, это не задача, а вопрос. на который вы, кстати, не ответили, хотя и написали якобы некий «ответ».

Comment: тем более и енамы уже есть

Comment: енамы? что это?

Comment: Вопрос был как инициализировать константы из интерфейса в конструкторе класса. Я показал как это делается. В чем ваши претензии я не понимаю.